# Umbraco Razor - Creating 2 lists and then determining which to choose

Tags: razor, umbraco

I have a tree structure in Umbraco 4.11.10 that uses 2 different types of "Detail Page" nodes.  One has dates and one has non-date "Detail Page" nodes.  I need to determine which list to show depending on if the children have the date property or not of the parent node that has the doctype of 'ListParent'.

I am able to create a list of the nodes, BUT I need to determine which list to show.

This is what I ultimate want:

Parent Node 1 (Doctype of 'ListParent')

- Node One (non date)
- Node Two(non date)
- Node Three(non date)

Parent Node 2 (Doctype of 'ListParent')

- Node One (date)
- Node Two(date)
- Node Three(date)

I am REALLY close with my code but I just need a little help determining which to show.  This is what I have so far below. I just need the IF statement to determine which list to show.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

```
@using umbraco.MacroEngines
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext

@{

if(@Model.Descendants().NodeTypeAlias == "Event"){@*Not Working*@
    @pageListingSorted()
}
else{
        <P>not sorted</P>
@pageListing()  
 }

}

@helper pageListing(){  
foreach(var item in @Model.Children.Where("!hideFromAllMenus")){
 var listImage = Library.MediaById(item.landingPageImage);
<div class="boxItem grid_4">

      @if(@item.HasValue("landingPageImage")){
        <a href="@item.Url">
        <img src="/imagegen.ashx?width=224&image=@listImage.Url" style="margin-left:-60px" />
        </a>
        <div class="boxButtons"></div>
             if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.buyNowLink))
            {
               <a href="@item.buyNowLink" class="buyNowBtn" title="Buy tickets to @item.Name"  onclick="pageTracker._link('@item.buyNowLink'); return false;">Buy Now</a>
            }

            <a href="@item.Url" class="learnMoreBtn">Learn More</a>
      }
      <h3>
            @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.altPageTitle))
            {
               <a href="@item.Url"> @item.altPageTitle</a>
            }
            else
            {
               <a href="@item.Url"> @item.Name</a>
            }
        </h3>


    </div>

 }

}
 @*END PAGE LISTING HELPER*@


 @helper pageListingSorted(){
 foreach(var item in   @Model.Children.Where("!hideFromAllMenus").Where("calendarEventDateTime != null").OrderBy("calendarEventDateTime")){
 var listImage = Library.MediaById(item.landingPageImage);
    <div class="boxItem grid_4">

      @if(@item.HasValue("landingPageImage")){
        <a href="@item.Url">
            @*--Added margin negative left for original images - Take out on Live--*@
        <img src="/imagegen.ashx?width=224&image=@listImage.Url" style="margin-left:-60px" />
        </a>
        <div class="boxButtons"></div>
             if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.buyNowLink))
            {
               <a href="@item.buyNowLink" class="buyNowBtn" title="Buy tickets to @item.Name"  onclick="pageTracker._link('@item.buyNowLink'); return false;">Buy Now</a>
            }

            <a href="@item.Url" class="learnMoreBtn">Learn More</a>
      }
      <h3>
            @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.altPageTitle))
            {
               <a href="@item.Url"> @item.altPageTitle</a>
            }
            else
            {
               <a href="@item.Url"> @item.Name</a>
            }
        </h3>
         @*Event Status*@
        @if (item.soldOut)
        {
            <p class="statusAlert">Sold Out</p>
        }
        else if (item.cancelled)
        {
            <p class="statusAlert">Cancelled</p>
        }
        else if (item.rescheduled)
        {
         <p class="statusAlert">Rescheduled</p>
        }
        else
        {
            <text></text>
        }
         @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.eventTimeHeader))
        {
            <div class="dateTimeHeader">@item.eventTimeHeader</div>
        } 

    </div>
  }

 }@*END PAGE LISTING SORTED HELPER*@
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be OK if your sortable children are of node type "Event" (children targets one level down - you only need to use descendants if you are checking many levels below):

```
if(@Model.Children().Where(x => x.NodeTypeAlias == "Event").Count() > 0) {
    @pageListingSorted()
}
else{
        <P>not sorted</P>
@pageListing()  
 }
```

Comment: That was really close. You did send me in the right direction though.  I was getting a Lamda and dynamic object error.  My solution is posted.

Answer (score 0):

The is the solution I found. Thanks @amelvin for helping me in the right direct.

```
if(@Model.Children.Where("NodeTypeAlias == \"Event\"").Count() > 0) {
    @pageListingSorted()
}
else{
 <P>not sorted</P>
@pageListing()  
 }
```